# How to copy array with jump?

Tags: java, arrays

In my JAVA program, I need to "insert" elements in an array to another array at specific locations with equal interval (4 elements). For example:

```
byte[] orig = new byte[100000];
byte[] target = new byte[100000*4];
for(int j=0;j<orig.length;j++)
    target[j*4]=orig[j];
```

The code above works fine but too slow - roughly 50 ms on my laptop. Is there some way that can do the same within a few ms?

Comment: In what context is 1/20th of a second too slow?

Comment: How much faster it works if you write `j` instead of `j*4`?

Comment: How did you time it? Did you time only the loop?

Comment: @Jongware, game development, for example. If you want 60 FPS, you have 16 ms per frame for everything. Anyway taking 50 ms to copy 100 KB of data on modern hardware is weird. Though Java checks range every time, so it might be the culprit here.

Comment: I'm doing video processing at 30 fps... Can only accept ms-level latency for this simple task. Using j instead j*4 doesn't help much. I test it using System.currentTimeMillis() and only time the loop.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` itself takes some milliseconds because it is a system call. You should use a profiler for this.

Comment: @m0skit0, I agree, but after the latency reduces to 10ms below. 50 ms is definitely too large...

Comment: So the problem here is not that you copy to every 4th item, but generally that copying by using `b[i] = a[i]` is slow.

Comment: And with `System.arraycopy`?

Comment: @n0rd, correct. But copying every 4th item blocks me from using System.arraycopy which is < 1ms.

Comment: You are likely wouldn't have this issue in unmanaged language, so it's not "universal for any programming languages", but specific to Java.

Comment: @n0rd: Agree with that.

Comment: You may want to look for 'array bounds check elimination in Java'. I am unaware about its current state in JVM but it did exist in early versions.

Comment: I'd agree with @n0rd for this one.  Java probably isn't the way to go for this project if you need really high-performance code.  C++ is calling you!

Answer (score 2):

If you reverse the way you are thinking about it by making `orig` the same size as `target` but access its indexes with a multiply, you can use `System.arraycopy`, `Arrays.copyOf` or `clone`, any of which might be faster. `arraycopy` should use a `memcpy` or something under the hood. `copyOf` probably calls `arraycopy`.

So i.e.

```
byte[] orig = new byte[100000 * 4];

// access index in orig
orig[i * 4] = ...;

byte[] copy = new byte[orig.length];
System.arraycopy(orig, 0, copy, 0, orig.length);
```

Note this will probably have worse cache performance since the array elements aren't contiguous anymore. (I don't know how much. Better to trust a profiler on that.)

Comment: It doesn't work in my case since the data in orig is not controlled by me. But it opens the door to many similar methods, one of which might work. Let me think.